# ssh <username>@<host> How do I find the user name and host name of my local machine?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, openssh

I just installed openssh on my Xubuntu machine using this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring). It's installed successfully which I checked by doing `ssh -v localhost`.

Now I want to ssh into this machine from my mac. I have my router pointed at 22 but I cant seem to figure out what the `username` and `host` should be to make this successful.

How do I find `ssh <username>@<host>` for my local machine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find the username, type

```
whoami
```

on the Xubuntu machine. Instead of "host", look for the IP address. For example, run

```
ifconfig
```

and look for something like `inet addr:192.168.0.100`

Answer (score 0):

Normally it uses the same username and password you use to log into your LINUX distro.

Comment: So how do you determine that? Suppose I inherit the machine and no one told me what this is?

Comment: If you inherit the machine and have no login and password to even use the machine then you have a bigger problem. If you need to use the existing ssh and it does not respond to the distros username and password you can always change the ssh password, reinstall it, setup a new key pair, etc.

Comment: @hwac121 surely there are a bajillion ways to set up auto-login for GNU/Linux, such that when you turn on the machine, it starts a shell or some sort of graphical environment with access to a terminal emulator of some kind...